# Remove text between comments

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In order to send query to execute with JDBC I have to remove texte between /* and */

```
/*==============================================================**/
/* Description : ... */
/* Author   : rgosse                                                  */
/* Date de création du script : 25/04/2013                    */
/*==============================================================*/

/*==============================================================*/
/* PISTE D'AUDIT                                                */
/*==============================================================*/
declare @username varchar(25)
declare @dateNow datetime
declare @contact_id numeric
...
```

can I do it with preg_replace ?

someting like

```
preg_replace("/[/*][^*\/]+\[*/]/","", $sql);
```

Comment: Have you read any tutorial about regular expressions or did you just put come random characters and expect it to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern

```
$code = preg_replace('~/\*(?>[^*]++|\*++(?!/))*\*++/~', '', $code);
```

Details:

```
~              # delimiter (instead of /, avoid to escape all the / in the pattern)
/              # literal /
\*             # literal * (must be escaped since it's a special character)
(?>            # open a non capturing group (atomic)
    [^*]++     # all characters except * one or more times
  |            # OR
    \*++(?!/)  # * one or more times not followed by /
)*             # repeat the group zero or more times (here * is a quantifier)
\*++           # * one or more times
/              # literal /
~              # pattern delimiter
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape chars like `/` and `*` because they have special meaning, you only have done it in one place. The code below should do the trick

```
 preg_replace("^/\/\*[^*\/]+\*\/$/","", $sql);
```

Comment: *Generally* `/` doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: You could remove the `*` from `[^\*\/]`, also `*` doesn't need to be escaped inside `[]` blocks.

Comment: `[^*\/]+` - this will interrupt on any `*` occurrence, so it won't match `/* * */`

Comment: @DevZer0: in general you can use almost any character as a delimiter - like `~` or `#`. In that case `/` will be a regular character

Answer (score 0):

To replace the text between the comments we need to match the beginning and ending comment and then replace the elements between those. Since `*` is a quanitifer we'll need to escape it `\*` so its natural behavior doesn't throw an error in PHP.

***Note:*** In the following, I'm assuming balanced comment marks.

```
$code = "
/*==============================================================**/
/* Description : ... */
/* Author   : rgosse                                                  */
/* Date de création du script : 25/04/2013                    */
/*==============================================================*/

/*==============================================================*/
/* PISTE D'AUDIT                                                */
/*==============================================================*/
declare @username varchar(25)
declare @dateNow datetime
declare @contact_id numeric
";

$pattern = "!(/\*).+(\*/)!";
$replacement = '/**/';

$newCode = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$code);

echo $newCode;
```

**Output:**

```
/**/
/**/
/**/
/**/
/**/

/**/
/**/
/**/
declare @username varchar(25)
declare @dateNow datetime
declare @contact_id numeric
```

If you want to replace all comments entirely, make the following change:

```
$replacement = '';
```